# Issue with Sorting List using collections in java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, guava, predicate

I have a list with Order Entries. Each order entry has a base price. I want to sort this list on entry.basePrice descending (enty.basePrice == 0 entries should be at the bottom).

In this list, either no entry will have 0 price or one entry will have. I am doing like this ..

```
final Collection<AbstractOrderEntryModel> orderEntry = Collections2.filter(source.getEntries(),
            new Predicate<AbstractOrderEntryModel>()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean apply(final AbstractOrderEntryModel arg)
                {
                    return arg.getBasePrice().doubleValue() == 0 ? true : false;
                }
            });
```

Here I m filtering my entry which having baseprice = 0.0
Now How I will remove and add this item `(orderEntry.iterator().next())` at last in OrderEntry List?

If its not a recommended solution, and it can be possible through Collections.sort also then please give me solution.

Comment: could you store these entries somewhere else and include them in the end after filtering?

Comment: You could write a custom Comparator that compares Order objects by its price. Then you sort with Collections.sort(...).

Comment: These twisted boolean expressions just go on forever… `arg.getBasePrice().doubleValue() == 0` **is** already either `true` or `false`. Why do you append `? true : false` to it, just to show off that you know the ternary operator?

Comment: @Holger I always ask why just once. Would `(arg.getBasePrice().doubleValue() == 0 ? true : false) ? true : false` be even better?

Comment: Hey guys my question is different, and you went to some another topic. Can you plz tell me some example also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to put an item matching a predicate at the end of the list. This can be done straightforward:

```
List<AbstractOrderEntryModel> list=source.getEntries()
final Collection<AbstractOrderEntryModel> orderEntry = Collections2.filter(list,
  new Predicate<AbstractOrderEntryModel>()
  {
    public boolean apply(final AbstractOrderEntryModel arg)
    {
        return arg.getBasePrice().doubleValue() == 0;
    }
  });
if(!orderEntry.isEmpty()) {
  assert orderEntry.size()==1; // so you said in your question
  AbstractOrderEntryModel e=orderEntry.iterator().next();
  list.remove(e);
  list.add(e);
}
```